# Protractor Pause On Failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am new to protractor and I am trying to figure out how to make the test/runner pause on failure.  Ideally I would love to transition to the nodejs debugger but am open to any suggestion.

My use case is basically, when a test fails I would like to see what state the UI is in to help understand why the test failed.

Nick.

Comment: How to use debugger to pause no matter what already [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373148/angular-protractor-leave-browser-open-after-e2e-tests/23374977#23374977) But pausing specifically upon failure is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put browser to sleep after or before your `expect` line to see what's going on.

```
browser.sleep(20000); // sleep 20 seconds
```

#### Update:

protractor now supports `.pause()` method.

```
browser.pause()
```

Read the docs here: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.pause

Comment: How does the browser.debugger() work ?  Every time I do it i dont see anything special happen...

Comment: @Nix you should run protractor with `--debug` flag and have `node-inspector` running to see it pauses

Comment: @Mohsen do you have a tutorial for this?

Comment: Is there a way to pause automatically on failure? I don't know in advance which test is going to fail, so now I'm running the test, adding `browser.pause()` before the failure, and then re-running the test. I wish there were a single-pass solution.

Comment: @DanielDarabos You can use Jasmine API to determine if test failed in `afterEach`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 9):

You can also add to the jasmine config, to stop when spec fails:
(same as how protractor-screenshot-reporter works)

for jasmine 1:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    exports.config = {
        onPrepare: function () {
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
                reportSpecResults: function (spec) {
                    if (!spec.results().passed()) {
                        spec.results().items_.forEach(function (v) {
                            console.log(v.trace.stack);
                        });
                        browser.pause();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

for jasmine2:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
        specDone: function (spec) {
            if (spec.status === 'failed') {
                console.dir(spec.failedExpectations.length);
                console.log(spec.failedExpectations[0].message);
                console.log(spec.failedExpectations[0].stack);
                browser.pause();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

then by typing "repl" in the console you switch to interactive mode, so you can try out the protractor commands.

Comment: Once the test failed, the spec is done, no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put browser.debugger() where you want your test to stop.

You have to have selenium standalone server running. You can start it using `webdriver-manager start` from command prompt.  In your configuration file for protractor you have to have entry for selenium server pointing to that server like 
`seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'`, and entry for chromeOnly should be set to false. Debugging only works for chrome browser. Once you run you application it will drop into nodejs debugger. You have to press 'c' to continue. Once you debug statement is hit, you can do F12 to open debugger, and under console, you can use window.clientSideScripts to see what you have. I myself am at this point, but documentation for clientSideScripts is non-existant, so you can type the name of the function and it will give you the function definition. Then, you can try to figure out parameters it expects.