# Angular Protractor - Leave browser open after E2E tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Is it possible to leave the test browser windows open after Angular Protractor tests run? I have a tough test failing in FireFox and it'd be useful to access the state of the web page to see what's going on.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use Protractor debug/pause feature to pause the e2e run which will ultimately leave the browser open: [more info here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#pausing-to-debug)

To do so, add this line on your protractor test before the failing one

```
browser.pause();
```

There is also a very useful tool called [elementor](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor) that you may want to take a look later on.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.   After entering "c" it just blows through all the tests and ignores the browser.debugger() line.  break in timers.js:79
  77 }
  78 
  79 function listOnTimeout() {
  80   var msecs = this.msecs;
  81   var list = this;
debug> c

Comment: If it blows the same way without debugger then is something else, unrelated to debug feature.

Comment: by "blows through the tests"  I meant that the addition of the browser.debugger() line has not affect.

Comment: Try new latest Protractor with `browser.pause();` and also [elementor](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor)

Answer (score 17):

`browser.pause` no longer works with current Node v8.1.0, see [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307), but you could use     `browser.sleep(10000);` to keep the browser open for e.g. 10 seconds

Answer (score 2):

If you configured the test script to run using grunt, you could use the following code:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: "protractor.conf.js",
        keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
        noColor: false // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
      },
      run: {}
    },
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: `keepAlive` didn't work for me. However, I was able to hold the browser from closing for a minute with `browser.sleep(60e3);`

Answer (score 2):

If you have Node 8+, bumped into issue [`"Error: Cannot find module '_debugger'"`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307) while attempting `browser.pause` solution from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374977/3233388) and you couldn't fix it using [this github solution](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307#issuecomment-355811744) then you can workaround it as follows:

1. Install protractor as a module of the automation framework (i.e. without `-g` flag)

   ```
   npm install protractor
   ```
2. Run `webdriver-manager update` for this protractor instance as well:

   ```
   node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
   ```
3. Where you have `browser.pause();` in your code, replace it with `debugger;` statement
4. Run your code as follows:

   ```
    node inspect ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractorConf.js
   ```

   Where `protractorConf.js` is the config file of your protractor instance
5. If `debugger` waits for an input from you at the command line, just type `cont` and hit enter (to `cont`inue the execution)

Answer (score 2):

## super simple solution, that does exactly what's needed

The idea is that you don't really want to keep alive the session but rather pause it for a very long time when tests are done and be able to resume on-close procedures at any time

So just add this to your `config.js`

```
    async onComplete() {
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        await browser.wait(
            async () => {
                let url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
                return url.includes('close/');
            },
            5 * 60 * 1000,
            'Keep-alive timeout reached, closing the session...',
        );
    },
```

What the code does is, after all tests passed or failed, it waits until you type and submit `close/` in browser's url field, or times out itself in 5 mins.

[image]

The reason `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` is needed here, because the browser opens an empty page when you type `close/` which is non angular

You can even improve it and make it conditional, based on a parameter you pass to protractor config

Comment: however there is another approach if you want to stop the browser on error