# How to stop automatically closing browser when writing protractor test cases

Tags: protractor

I am new to writing test cases using protractor for non angular application. I wrote a sample test case.Here the browser closes automatically after running test case.How can I prevent this. Here is my code

```
var submitBtnElm = $('input[data-behavior=saveContribution]');

      it('Should Search', function() {
        browser.driver.get('http://localhost/enrollments/osda1.html');   
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('contributePercentValue')).sendKeys(50);
        submitBtnElm.click().then(function() {

        });
      });
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit more? What do you mean by browser closes automatically? Shouldn't your browser close once it completes running your script? Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur I want to perform a click action. But the browser closes before triggering click.I have updated code in the question.

Comment: Is there any log in the console after the window closes?  What does protractor/jasmine report at the end?

Comment: I'm guessing the window is closing because your locator looks incorrect and it's throwing an error, you are missing quotes around the attribute.  should be `var submitBtnElm = $('input[data-behavior="saveContribution"]');`

Comment: Here a simple but a working answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205388/9150146

Comment: This is a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373148/angular-protractor-leave-browser-open-after-e2e-tests/62205388#62205388 didn't want to duplicate it

Comment: This is a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373148/angular-protractor-leave-browser-open-after-e2e-tests/62205388#62205388 didn't want to duplicate it

Answer (score 16):

I was also struggling with a similar issue where i had a test case flow where we were interacting with multiple application and when using Protractor the browser was closing after executing one conf.js file. Now when I looked into the previous response it was like adding delay which depends on how quick your next action i performed or it was hit or miss case. Even if we think from debugging perspective most of the user would be performing overnight runs and they would want to have browser active for couple of hours before they analyze the issue. So I started looking into the protractor base code and came across a generic solution which can circumvent this issue, independent of any browser. Currently the solution is specific to requirement that browser should not close after one conf.js file is executed, then could be improved if someone could add a config parameter asking the user whether they want to close the browser after their run.

The browser could be reused for future conf.js file run by using tag --seleniumSessionId in command line.

Solution:

- Go to ..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built where your
  protractor is installed.
- Open driverProvider.js file and go to function quitDriver
- Replace **return driver.quit()** by ***return 0***

As far as my current usage there seems to be no side effect of the code change, will update if I came across any other issue due to this change. Snapshot of code snippet below.

Thanks
Gleeson

**Snapshot of code snippet:**
[image: Snapshot of code snippet]

Comment: Hi Gleeson - you should consider posting your code directly in your answer.  It will make it easier to index and reference.

Answer (score 11):

Add `browser.pause()` at the end of your it function.  Within the function itself.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, either inside the function or outside

Answer (score 7):

I found Gleeson's solution is working, and that really helped me. The solution was...

1. Go to %APPDATA%Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\
2. Find driverProviders.js
3. Open it in notepad or any other text editor
4. Find and Replace return driver.Quit() to return 0
5. Save the file

Restart your tests after that.

I am using 
node v8.12.0
npm v6.4.1
protractor v5.4.1

This solution will work, only if you installed npm or protractor globally; if you have installed your npm or protractor locally (in your folder) then, you have to go to your local protractor folder and do the same.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use `browser.driver.sleep(500);` before your click operation.

See this.

```
browser.driver.sleep(500);

element(by.css('your button')).click();
browser.driver.sleep(500);
```

Comment: i have a similar problem, i use browser.sleep(1000); but it didn't solve my problem i even change  DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL= 120000; but no result always all my tests are passed before even the page is loaded !

Comment: Adding sleeps like this not a good practice. Please see below solution if you have use callback functions to keep the browser window open

Answer (score 4):

Add a callback function in `It` block and the browser window doesn't close until you call it.
So perform the action that you need and place the callback at your convenience

```
var submitBtnElm = $('input[data-behavior=saveContribution]');
  it('Should Search', function(callback) {
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost/enrollments/osda1.html');   
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('contributePercentValue')).sendKeys(50);
    submitBtnElm.click().then(function() {
       // Have all the logic you need
       // Then invoke callback
       callback();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to make **browser** NOT to close for some time, Use  *browser.wait()*. Inside the wait function write logic for checking either visibilityOf() or invisibilityOf() of an element, which is not visible or it will take time to become invisible on UI. In this case wait() keep on checking the logic until either condition met or timeout reached. You can increase the timeout if you want browser visible more time.

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var submitBtnElm = $('input[data-behavior=saveContribution]');

it('Should Search', function() {
   browser.driver.get('http://localhost/enrollments/osda1.html');   
   browser.driver.findElement(by.id('contributePercentValue')).sendKeys(50);
   submitBtnElm.click().then(function() {
   browser.wait(function(){
            EC.invisibilityOf(submitBtnElm).call().then(function(isPresent){
                if(isPresent){
                    return true;
                }
            });
        },20000,'error message');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a change triggered on your page by the button click. It might be something as subtle as a class change on an element or as obvious as a `<p></p>` element with the text "Saved" displayed. What I would do is, after the test, explicitly wait for this change.

```
[...]
return protractor.browser.wait(function() {
    return element(by.cssContainingText('p', 'Saved')).isPresent();
}, 10000);
```

You could add such a wait mechanism to the `afterEach()` method of your spec file, so that your tests are separated even without the Protractor Angular implicit waits.

Answer (score 2):

```
var submitBtnElm = $('input[data-behavior=saveContribution]');

  it('Should Search', function() {
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost/enrollments/osda1.html');   
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('contributePercentValue')).sendKeys(50);
    submitBtnElm.click().then(function() {

    });
    browser.pause(); // it should leave browser alive after test
  });
```

browser.pause() should leave browser alive until you let it go.

@Edit Another approach is to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` before browser.get(...). Protractor wouldn't wait for Angular loaded and you could use usual element(...) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor will close browsers, that it created, so an approach that I am using is to start the browser via the [webdriver-reuse-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-reuse-session) npm package.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of this package

It is a new package, so let me know if it solves your problem. I am using it with great success.