# Browser automatically closed before test run in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm new to Protractor. I'm writing a script to test my web site. But, Browser opens and closes. I couldn't even get to see what happens. Can someone tell me what to do?

This is my configuration.js

```
  exports.config = {
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
      specs: ['HomePageObjectSpec.js'],
      onPrepare: function () {  
         browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1680, 1050);
      },
   }
```

Here is my test.js

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('my url');

    element(by.css('.btn')).click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better do a Google search before posting questions here.  Check my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933945/how-to-stop-automatically-closing-browser-when-writing-protractor-test-cases/35979832#35979832)

Or

For quick learn, just put a `browser.driver.sleep(500);` before  or after your operations. Hope this helps. :)